# How to fill a 2D array from bottom left to top right in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to fill a 2D array with stars in a specific pattern, specifically from bottom left to the top right corner. [image: You can see that I've got it the way I would like going from top left to the bottom right, but I can't seem to get the last couple of points when going from bottom left to top right]

```
public static char[][] rightDiagonal (char star, int dimensions){
    char [][] array = new char [dimensions][dimensions];
    int last = dimensions - 1; // create variable for last number in array
    // for loop to create right diagonal pattern
    for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < dimensions; j++)
            if (i == j)
                array [i][last-i] = star;
            else 
                array [i][j] = ' ';
        }
    return array;
```

This is what I've tried and the best result I've gotten is the result I've posted in the image.

Comment: try `array [i][j] = (last-i == j ? '*' : ' ');` instead of the If statement

Comment: I tried the method you previously posted and that worked. I also tried what you posed there and it also worked. I'm not super sound on the '?' principle and its uses. Seems like a lot of people use it so I'm start looking through more info on it.

Comment: You'll get used to it. It's like a mini IF..ELSE.

Comment: Funny enough, the `if` is an expression in Kotlin. It does the same thing as `expression ? expression : expression` but it is more readable. This is one of the few instances where Java is possibly *too* concise (and, of course, the construct has been taken from C, which is where most of the Java syntax originated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want an array with stars from bottom-left to top-right, try this loop. It uses the ternary operator but you could stick to your IF if you want.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dimensions; j++)
        array[i][j] = (last-i == j ? '*' : ' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You easily loop trought:

for (int i = dimensions-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
array [i][i] = star;

Comment: I need to be able to leave ' ' in the other elements to format the chart appropriately

Answer (score 0):

```
diagonal=dimension-1
for (int i=0; i<dimension; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<dimension;j++) {
         if (j==diagonal) {
            array [i][j] = star;
            diagonal --;
         else array [i][j] = "_PUT HERE WATH YOU WANT OR LEAVE IT BLANK_"
    }
 }
```